# Excel 365 Worksheet Array-Formula to Return Values NOT Found?

Tags: excel, worksheet-function

What array formula will return values which *don't* appear in another list?

Example:
Cells named `ShortList` contain (one word per cell):

```
How recent  neuroscience    research    points  the way towards defeating   adversarial examples    and achieving   a   more    resilient   consistent  and flexible    form    of  artificial  intelligence
```

And cells named `LongList` contain:

```
a   about   above   across  and how however i   instead more    neither never   nevertheless    next    no  of  second  several shall   she the towards
```

Here's the expected output of the formula:

```
recent  neuroscience    research    points  way defeating   adversarial examples    achieving   resilient   consistent  flexible    form    artificial  intelligence
```

I'm thinking it might involve, match, xmatch, lookup, or xlookup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think i got it. This returns the expected result in my question.

```
=FILTER(ShortList, ISNA(MATCH(ShortList, LongList, 0)))
```

hoping to see alternate answers.

Answer (score 2):

When your `FILTER()` formula works fine but for large dataset `LET()` may give you twice faster performance as per [Microsoft Documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/let-function-34842dd8-b92b-4d3f-b325-b8b8f9908999#:%7E:text=The%20LET%20function%20assigns%20names,through%20Excel%27s%20native%20formula%20syntax.)

```
=LET(x,A1:A3,y,ISNUMBER(MATCH(x,B1:B10,0)),FILTER(x,y=FALSE))
```

With name manager try-

```
=LET(x,ShortList,y,ISNUMBER(MATCH(x,LongList,0)),FILTER(x,y=FALSE))
```

[image]

Comment: To save repeating `A1:A3`, you could use `=LET(x,A1:A3,y,ISNUMBER(MATCH(x,B1:B10,0)),FILTER(x,y=TRUE))`

Comment: This isn't giving me expected results. Is this correct? `=LET(x,ShortList,y,ISNUMBER(MATCH(ShortList,LongList,0)),FILTER(x,y=TRUE))`

Comment: This give me correct result, try it `=LET(x,ShortList,y,ISNUMBER(MATCH(x,LongList,0)),FILTER(x,y=TRUE))`.

Comment: Harun24HR's and both of @chrisneilsen's formulae all give me the same unexpected result. I'm going to add my actual sample data and output to my question.

Comment: I think you need to filter `FALSE` results from match function. Give a try `=LET(x,A1:A3,y,ISNUMBER(MATCH(x,B1:B10,0)),FILTER(x,y=FALSE))`.

Comment: That one works. Thx! Maybe you could add to your answer, with the benefits over my answer? Plz use my names: `=LET(x,ShortList,y,ISNUMBER(MATCH(x,LongList,0)),FILTER(x,y=FALSE))`

Comment: i think you don't mean "with name manager". Just, "with named ranges". The way it's written sounds like you're entering the formula into the name manager.

Comment: Yes, with named range.

Comment: i see no performance difference between my version, without Let, and your version, with Let. I filled a sheet with your formula, from A1:V19997. Did the same with my formula, on another sheet. Calculate Sheet takes same time on both sheets (about 10 seconds). Note, i did this with Control-Shift-Enter, otherwise the spills would collide and give errors.

Comment: Thx for your answer. I learned something. Just sharing why i didn't select yours as the answer: 1) LET gives performance gain only when a computation is repeated more than once. In your formula, the computation isn't repeated, so there's no advantage. 2) You didn't put part of your computation, `= false`, in the LET. 3) My answer is shorter, and contains fewer functions. 4) Your first post didn't work. Thx!

Comment: No issue. I just shown you other way to solve. Your one is good enough.

Comment: Mine mentions ShortList twice, but i think that's not a performance-hit, because it's just a cell reference, not a computation.

Comment: Other drawbacks of this answer: using `x` for `ShortList` is redundant, as `ShortList` is already a name -- and might be a performance-hit. Using `y`, instead of meaningful variable-names, like `Found`.